# Windows Authentication User Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, windows-authentication

I am working on a project that uses an ASP.NET MVC application which has a page on there that only certain users should be able to access. Using Windows Authentication, I want to take the User.Identity.Name and check that against the LogonID field in my Users table in the database. If there is a match, I then want to check if the IsAdmin field equals true and if so, grant access to the desired page.

I am fairly new to this so I was wondering how I would need to go about it?

**UPDATE:**

So i've tried to use the AuthorizeAttribute which has been suggested to me but I have come across a problem.

I am using a SQL Server Compact Database without a DBContext. So I was wondering how I would write my entity in order to access the database?

```
public class AuthorizeAuthorAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    //Entity to access Database
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }
        string currentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name; 

        var userName = //Linq statement 

        string my = userName.ToString();

        if (currentUser.Contains(my))                       
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a custom authorization filter that does what you need.

Comment: @WiktorZychla please see update and advise if you can help further

Answer (score 0):

You could implement custom Authorize filter and decorate the required controller with this filter. Inside custom filter Authorize core method, check the windows identity against your database and return true/false accordingly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore(v=vs.118).aspx